# Cascading Dropdown - How to load Data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, fetch-api

I try to make an cascading dropdown, but I have problems with the sending and fetching of the response data.

Backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CascadeDropDowns(string type, int id)
{  .............
 return Json(model);
}
```

Here I get the correct data.

First I tried:

```
$("#dropdown").change( function () {
   var valueId = $(this).val();
   var name = $(this).attr("id");
   let data = new URLSearchParams();
   data.append("type", name);
   data.append("id", valueId);
   fetch("@Url.Action("CascadeDropDowns", "Home")", {
         method: "POST",
         credentials: "include",
         headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
         },
         body: data
    })
    
  .then(response => {
        console.log('Success:', response);
         return response.json();
   })
  .then(json  => {
     console.log('Success:', json );
      console.log('data:', json.Projects);
     PopulateDropDown("#subdropdown1",json.Projects)
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error:', error);
   });
});
```

Here I can send the Request and get a "success" back. However, when I access `json.Projects` I just get an `undefined. I have tried to change the Content-Type, without success.

Secondly I have used:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("CascadeDropDowns", "Home")",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        contentType:  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
      },
        error: function (r) {
             console.log(r.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
             console.log(r.responseText);
        }
     });
```

With this I get an *Illegal Invocation* Error.

What do I have to do that get either of those working? What are their problems?

Comment: What issue you are having with, could you please share? Meanwhile, you could [`have a look cascading dropdown sample`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358064/how-to-create-cascading-dropdown/72360257#72360257)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to make an cascading dropdown, but I have problems with the
> sending and fetching of the response data.What do I have to do that get either of those working? What are their problems?

Well, let consider the first approach, you are trying to retrieve response like `json.Projects` but its incorrect because data is not there and you are getting undefined as below:

[image]

**Solution:**

Your response would be in `json` instead of `json.Projects`

Complete Demo:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="ddlState"></select>
        <br />

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
            var ddlState = $('#ddlState');
            ddlState.empty();
            ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Please wait ...'));


            let data = new URLSearchParams();
            data.append("type", "INDIA");
            data.append("id", 101);

            fetch("http://localhost:5094/ReactPost/CascadeDropDowns", {
                method: "POST",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
                },
                body: data
            })

                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(result => {

                    console.log(result);
                    var ddlState = $('#ddlState');
                    ddlState.empty();
                    ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Select State'));

                    $.each(result, function (index, states) {
                        ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val(states.cityId).html(states.cityName));
                    });


                })
```

**Second approach:**

In `ajax` request you are passing object as object fahsion like `data: data` whereas, your controller expecting as parameter consequently, you are getting following error:

[image]

**Solution:**

You should pass your data within your ajax request like this way `data: { type: "YourTypeValue", id:101 },` instead of `data: data,`

Complete Sample:

```
          $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:5094/ReactPost/CascadeDropDowns',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { type: "YourValue", id:101 },
                success: function (response) {

                    ddlState.empty();
                    ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Select State'));
                    $.each(response, function (i, states) {
                        ddlState.append($("<option></option>").val(states.cityId).html(states.cityName));
                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });
```

**Note:** I have ommited `contentType` because, by default `contentType` is   `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"` if we don't define.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hmm do I get this correctly. The problem with the fetch was that the json String is wrong? I have basically tried to access json.projects, although it would be more correct so say that the Json Object is already projects? And therefore can directly grab the values? Why did I then get a {} in the Response Header?

Do I have to change anything if I want to cascade multiple Dropdowns from this DDL? (Projects, Participants, Departments)

Comment: While, this statement executed `return response.json()` afterwards, in `.then(result =>` you will get the object directly inside arrow function `=>` value will be in `result` in your case only  `json`. So `"And therefore can directly grab the values?"` yes this is the case. I have already provided complete demo please try that. In addition, you can [`have a look here as well`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358064/how-to-create-cascading-dropdown/72360257#72360257)